# Nginx for a site allowing downloads

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, optimization

My friend have a site that allows users to download files.However the moment one guy start downloading server load change from 0.00 to 3.50 in a matter of minutes.Nginx and php-fpm reach D state and IOwait is like 100% on all cpu cores.I tried to limit number of concurrent connection but this seems to have no effect on server load.

```
user              nginx;
worker_processes  4;



events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;
gzip  on;
#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  2;
```

My php-fpm setting

```
pm.max_children = 7
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 6
pm.max_requests = 500
```

Server - 8gb ram 
Quad core processor 
1TB sata hdd

Comment: How many workers does downloading a file consume? (should only be one)

Comment: @foocorpluser how can i find out how many workers downloading a file consume .Thanks for quick response

Comment: lsof and grep should do it.

Comment: Dude i am relatively new to server management , could you please give me a detailed tutorial

Comment: lsof  | grep nginx  | grep TCP     You will see workers "LISTEN"(ing) and workers with "ESTABLISHED" connections, with the establisehd connections you can see the ip address that is connected. It should only take one worker establishing one connection to one ip to transfer one file.